# Templates: recurse until appropriate parameters are deduced

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I have some files which contain data, and a function `peekType()` which can recognise the files' data types. Various functionality will depend on what the data types turn out to be. The number of files to be considered should not be hard-coded.

I figured I would pass a list of file names to a function, and recursively pop those filenames off of the parameter pack until the definition matched some base case, at which point the base case would take over. Like so:

```
//Base case
template<class tA, class tB>
int PerformAlgorithm(std::vector<tA> a, std::vector<tB>){
  //Do stuff
}

//Recursive part
template<typename... Arguments >
int PerformAlgorithm(std::string inputfile, Arguments ... args){
  switch(peekType(inputfile)){
    case TYPE_BYTE:    {
      std::vector<uint8_t> arr;
      return PerformAlgorithm(args..., arr);
    }
    case TYPE_FLOAT:  {
      std::vector<double> arr;
      return PerformAlgorithm(args..., arr);
    }
    default:
      std::cerr<<"Unrecognised type!"<<std::endl;
      return -1;
  }
}

PerformAlgorithm("fileA", "fileB");
```

Unfortunately, the above never reaches the base case, yielding issues such as:

```
cannot convert ‘args#0’ (type ‘std::vector<double>’) to type ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’
```

Where am I going wrong?

An alternative attempt I made based on the template metaprogramming factorial examples also foundered.

Comment: I've reproduced a similar scenario and it works.

Comment: [Similar Scenario Here](https://ideone.com/pfz9Yg). It could be useful

Comment: Thanks, @BiagioFesta: I'll look into that: it's a nice MWE! (Except for the way the PRNG is misused.)

Comment: @BiagioFesta: Found the issue. I'd been starting the recursion with too many arguments :-/ Thanks! If you'd like to submit your MWE as an answer (with the PRNG cleaned up), I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here The Solution](https://ideone.com/pfz9Yg).

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void foo(const std::vector<A>& va,
         const std::vector<B>& vb) {
  std::cout << "-----The end of recursion-----\n"
      "Type VectorA: " << typeid(A).name() << "\n"
      "Type VectorB: " << typeid(B).name() << "\n"
      "----------------------------------------\n";
}

template<typename... Args>
void foo(std::string str, Args... args) {
  int number = give_me_anumber();
  if (number == 0) {
    std::vector<int> vector;
    foo(args..., vector);
  } else if (number == 1) {
    std::vector<double> vector;
    foo(args..., vector);
  }
}
```

As we've already written in the comments your design works, the problem was in the calling function.